# Using RssHttpHandlerBase in RssToolkit?

Tags: c#, reflection, rss, toolkit, strong-typing

I have a couple of RSS sources that I am querying with through the .Net [RssToolkit](http://aspnetrsstoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/3674).

What I would like is some basic instruction on how to make use of the RssHttpHandlerBase.  I know the toolkit comes with a command-line tool that will create a strongly-typed class for me, based on the feed provided, but I'm not entirely clear on how to implement that custom class.

I will be retrieving several sources from a database, which will need to match up to a strongly-typed class.  I'm guessing this I will accomplish through reflection?

The rss source objects populated from the db will contain the rss source, and the assembly name to use for parsing.

Again, an example would be nice.

I know this is the right approach, over a bunch of "if" statements.  Some guidance and examples would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this article: http://codingphobia.com/2009/07/06/how-to-consume-an-rss-feed-using-system-servicemodel-syndication-framework-part-2/

Comment: While that's a great library, upon my first set of tests with it, an exception is thrown: "The element with name 'RDF' and namespace 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#' is not an allowed feed format."  when attempting to query the following RSS Feed:  http://chicago.craigslist.org/search/ele?query=ipod&srchType=A&minAsk=&maxAsk=&format=rss